# Passing Arguments to RStripe

Tags: r

I'm having a little trouble with pagination in RStripe.  There is little by way of example in the documentation.

stripe_list_charges("API_KEY", args=NULL)

I want to set the arguments to use the limit = 100.

I've done the trial and error thing for an hour now but can't figure out the syntax.  ANy assistance appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? `stripe_list_charges("your key here", list(limit=100)` seems to be what the docs say. What happens? Is it ingnored? Or error messages?

Comment: You've answered my question!  Thank you so much. "list(limit=100)" was the answer!